# How to make a string clickable using Twui?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, twui

I have a project base on twitter's [twui framework](https://github.com/twitter/twui).I'm trying  to made a string clickable just like

```
[s addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"http://apple.com/" range:attrRange];
```

in NSMutableAttributedString, or performing a selector when clicked.

TUITextRender can draw a NSAttributedString, but "NSLinkAttributeName" doesn't work.

I can't find any method or delegate to solve this in TUITextView too.

How can I done this with twui?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same issue and I have totally no idea how to make it.

Comment: A bit late, but you'd have to modify the framework's NSMutableAttributedString+Additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read source code, I figured it out.

1. Store ranges in a array of `ABActiveRange` (Which contains in twui) subclass.
2. Implement `TUITextRendererDelegate` in your `UIViewController`.
3. In the `activeRangesForTextRenderer:` delegate method, return the array you made in step 1.
4. Enjoy ~